# LaTeX matrix formatting

Tags: amsmath, matrices, vector

I am trying to create something similar to the below image. I have something, but my formatting is a little off. How can I correct the formatting and also add the `W1`, `W2`, `Wn` and `D` letters on top (not a major issue however)?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
   \begin{bmatrix}
           W_{11} \\
           W_{12} \\
           \vdots \\
           W_{1n}
   \end{bmatrix}
   &+ \begin{bmatrix}
           W_{21} \\
           W_{22} \\
           \vdots \\
           W_{2n}
       \end{bmatrix}
   &+ \hdots
   &+ \begin{bmatrix}
           W_{n1} \\
           W_{n2} \\
           \vdots \\
           W_{nn}
       \end{bmatrix}
   &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{W_{11} + W_{21} + \hdots + W_{n1}}{n} \\
           \frac{W_{12} + W_{22} + \hdots + W_{n2}}{n} \\
           \vdots \\
           \frac{W_{1n} + W_{2n} + \hdots + W_{nn}}{n}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following sets the arrangement inside an `array`, with the first row handling the labels on top of each `bmatrix`, while the second row sets each of the matrices/vectors. [`\arraystretch` has been increased to spread the content vertically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% No column separation in array; manual spacing
                               % by supplying empty groups {} around operators
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Stretch out content vertically
  \begin{array}{ *{8}{c} }
    % Header row in \scriptstyle
    \scriptstyle W_1 & & % + 
    \scriptstyle W_2 & & % + ... +
    \scriptstyle W_n & & & % = 1/n
    \scriptstyle D \\
    % Matrix/vector row
    \begin{bmatrix}
      W_{11} \\ W_{12} \\ \vdots \\ W_{1n}
    \end{bmatrix}
    & {} + {} &
    \begin{bmatrix}
      W_{21} \\ W_{22} \\ \vdots \\ W_{2n}
    \end{bmatrix}
    & {} + \dots + {} &
    \begin{bmatrix}
      W_{n1} \\ W_{n2} \\ \vdots \\ W_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix}
    & {} = {} &
    \dfrac{1}{n} &
    \begin{bmatrix}
      W_{11} + W_{21} + \dots + W_{n1} \\
      W_{12} + W_{22} + \dots + W_{n2} \\
      \vdots \\
      W_{1n} + W_{2n} + \dots + W_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Since scalar multiplication of a vector results in each component being multiplied by the scalar, some simplification in the presentation makes things line up nicely.

For numbering the equation, you probably want to consider the following solution; it sets the equation number on the math axis.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}% No column separation in array; manual spacing
                               % by supplying empty groups {} around operators
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% Stretch out content vertically
  \mathop{\begin{bmatrix}
    W_{11} \\ W_{12} \\ \vdots \\ W_{1n}
  \end{bmatrix}}^{W_1}
  +
  \mathop{\begin{bmatrix}
    W_{21} \\ W_{22} \\ \vdots \\ W_{2n}
  \end{bmatrix}}^{W_2}
  + \dots +
  \mathop{\begin{bmatrix}
    W_{n1} \\ W_{n2} \\ \vdots \\ W_{nn}
  \end{bmatrix}}^{W_n}
  =
  \dfrac{1}{n}
  \mathop{\begin{bmatrix}
    W_{11} + W_{21} + \dots + W_{n1} \\
    W_{12} + W_{22} + \dots + W_{n2} \\
    \vdots \\
    W_{1n} + W_{2n} + \dots + W_{nn}
  \end{bmatrix}}^{D}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The math doesn't make sense though...

Comment: Thats awesome! its looks better than what I was expecting. How would I reference this though in a document? The math is from a Natural Language Processing model where we have many documents and train a model to output vectors for each word. Once we have these vectors we average them to obtain a single vector for each document. Some better explanation here: http://yaronvazana.com/2018/09/20/average-word-vectors-generate-document-paragraph-sentence-embeddings/

Comment: The usual method for referencing such a structure is to give it an equation number.  Instead of using `\[ ... \]`, wrap it in an `equation` environment, with a `\label{...}` inside.

Comment: @user113156: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

A proposition with the `mmatrix`  environment (medium size matrix) from `nccmath` and `cellspace` for a proper row spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2pt}

\newenvironment{bmmatrix}{\begin{bmatrix} \begin{mmatrix}}{\end{mmatrix}\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
\begin{matrix}
W_1 \\
   \begin{bmmatrix}
           W_{11} \\
           W_{12} \\[-1.5ex]
           \vdots \\
           W_{1n}
   \end{bmmatrix}
\end{matrix} &+ &
\begin{matrix}
W_2 \\
\begin{bmmatrix}
           W_{21} \\
           W_{22} \\[-1.5ex]
           \vdots \\
           W_{2n}
       \end{bmmatrix}
\end{matrix}
   &+ \hdots{}
   &
+ \begin{matrix}
W_n \\
\begin{bmmatrix}
           W_{n1} \\
           W_{n2} \\[-1.5ex]
           \vdots \\
           W_{nn}
\end{bmmatrix}
\end{matrix}
   &=
\begin{matrix}
D \\
\begin{bmatrix}
           \mfrac{W_{11} + W_{21} + \hdots + W_{n1}}{n} \\[-1ex]
          \smash[b]{ \vdots }\\[-0.5ex]
           \mfrac{W_{1n} + W_{2n} + \hdots + W_{nn}}{n}
    \end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of the `\overset` command from the `amsmath` package; this lines up your code with the intended meaning, and avoids setting up any extra array structures for the contents of your equation.

If you've got a scalar factor next to a matrix (as suggested in another answer), then `\overbrace` makes it clear that the scalar factor is included within the annotated object.

[image: Matrices annotated with \overset and \overbrace]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \overset{W_{1}}{
      \begin{bmatrix}
      W_{11} \\ W_{12} \\ \vdots \\ W_{1n}
    \end{bmatrix}}
%
    +
%
    \overset{W_{2}}{\begin{bmatrix}
      W_{21} \\ W_{22} \\ \vdots \\ W_{2n}
    \end{bmatrix}}
%
    +\dots+
%
    \overset{W_{n}}{\begin{bmatrix}
      W_{n1} \\ W_{n2} \\ \vdots \\ W_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix}}
%
    =
%
   \overbrace{ \dfrac{1}{n}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      W_{11} + W_{21} + \dots + W_{n1} \\
      W_{12} + W_{22} + \dots + W_{n2} \\
      \vdots \\
      W_{1n} + W_{2n} + \dots + W_{nn}
    \end{bmatrix}}^{D}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle}

\[
\begin{bNiceArray}{C}[first-row]
W_1 \\
W_{11} \\ 
W_{12} \\ 
\Vdots \\
W_{1n}
\end{bNiceArray}
+
\begin{bNiceArray}{C}[first-row]
W_1 \\
W_{21} \\ 
W_{22} \\ 
\Vdots \\
W_{2n}
\end{bNiceArray}
+
\cdots
+
\begin{bNiceArray}{C}[first-row]
W_n \\
W_{n1} \\ 
W_{n2} \\ 
\Vdots \\
W_{nn}
\end{bNiceArray}
=
\begin{bNiceArray}{C}[first-row]
D \\
\frac{W_{11}+W_{21}+\cdots+W_{n1}}{n} \\ 
\Vdots \\[5mm]
\frac{W_{1n}+W_{2n}+\cdots+W_{nn}}{n} 
\end{bNiceArray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]